# Disp_E_Exception when clicking "View Windows Settings" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2019

Currently using a pretty fresh install of Visual Studio 2019, and when clicking the "View Windows Settings" button to create a manifest file, I just get this error dialog:

[image: screenshot]

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your feedback!

This is fixed in the latest version of Visual Studio (16.4 Preview 4): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#16.4.0-pre.4.0